# Clone external e-sata drive to external e-sata

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata

I have a pair of e-SATA II drives that have been corrupted in a Windows Media Server NAS device.  Before I launch into system repair, I would like to clone both of these drives to ensure I can recover as much of the data as possible.

I have several laptops and a good sized desktop "workstation-class" machine (Dell T7500), but none of them seem to have multiple external e-SATA ports.

What's the easiest way to get set up to clone external drive A onto external drive B?

I see a wide range of dubious products on the market for external enclosures, port multipliers, etc.  It's the second time I'm having to do this, so I'd like to just get the "right" solution.

Comment: Do you have enough free disk space to clone in parts? E.g. read from disk A to an image on the internal HDD, then change drives and clone from the image to the new changed external drive? Also, eSATA is plain SATA compatible. You can hook them up to normal SATA cables. (The difference is the connector and a higher voltage when signaling).

Comment: Not without rejiggering internal disks.  Was hoping to be able to do a simple, point to point copy.  They're 2TB drives in this case, and I just have a 512MB SSD in the laptop.

Comment: So I guess I could get the right cables and connect them to the mainboard in the tower -- haven't looked but I assume it has a bunch of internal ports.

Comment: Is there some standard way of bringing some internal SATA ports out to a front panel so this wouldn't be gerry-rigged and require yanking the cover off the machine each time?

Comment: The standard way is called eSATA. An alternative is using an external box. In the case of an external box with a single [e]SATA connection you would need a [port multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier).  Technically that should *just work*. In practise you will run into problems where one device only supports one standard and the other device another standard. Or with a buggy BIOS which never considered all the options and which just works most of the time.

Comment: Any recommendations for a specific 2-3 bay enclosure with a port multiplier?  The last time I paid attention to things at this level I had to terminate a SCSI ribbon cable, so forgive my ignorance...

Comment: Sadly no. I usually have enough with a **single** eSATA option which I connect to [this dock](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wBUCD.png). If I need to mess with multiple SATA drives I just open the case and use the motherboards power plus SAS/SATA ports.  Port multipliers would work and I looked at them but found them too expensive. So I just use plain [e]SATA and SAS cards.  Your question is only one hour old though, give it some time and other people will answer.